# He is a Captain with the big letter. ( = great captain?)

Tags: capitalization, emphasis

I suspect this sentence would not sound idiomatic and clear:

*He is a Captain with the big letter.*

Is there a way to rephrase it slightly to mean

*He is a wonderful captain.*

Because
*He is THE captain.* is neutral in meaning and doesn't quite mean the same.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably thinking of the idiom "with a capital [first letter]," like "He's a Captain with a capital 'C.'" You're right; this doesn't mean quite what you're looking for; it is a way of emphasizing the word and meaning "He's *very much* a captain," or "he's a captain in every way that makes someone a captain," or simply "in an important way." Note, this expression could be used even when it would not actually be typical written style to use a capital letter. Like "He's not just a painter, he's an 'Artist' with a capital 'A.'" You might also occasionally hear the word "big" used in a construction like "The art museum ignores folk crafts and concerns itself with big-'A'-Art," meaning some kind of notion about "high art"; the "big" or capital 'A' implies weight and importance.

If your goal is to say "wonderful," why not say that? I don't think you can press capitalization into service to speak about merit.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! What about the punctuation in 'He is an Artist with a capital A.' ?  There are no quotations marks around 'trouble' and 'T' in a dictionary example of 'He's trouble with a capital T!'

Comment: @Mamamia Those are stylistic questions, and there's no official right way. Many style guides recommend using quote marks when talking about a letter, as I did. Some might recommend italics, I suppose. And often especially in informal writing you might use nothing at all, as in the example you found.

Comment: You've got trouble -- right here in River City -- with a capital T and that rhymes with P and that stands for Pool!

Comment: Which of these are more idiomatic, common and which less?

This is a Scandal with a capital S.
This is a big-'S'-Scandal.
This is very much a scandal. 
This is a heck of a scandal.

Comment: At least in Britain, if I say that someone is an artist with a capital A, or a boss with a capital B, or a leader with a capital L, there will often be a very strong element of irony, and an suggestion of vanity and pretence on the part of the person being discussed.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey So with most abstract notions this expression would not produce any clear meaning? What about 'This is a System with a capital S'? Or 'This is a Spoon with a capital S'? Or 'This is a cat with a capital C'?

Comment: @Mamamia - In general saying that 'This is a _Thing_ with a capital _First letter of Thing_' just means 'this _whatever_ is very much a _whatever_ according to some set of values', e.g. this is a Dog with a capital D could mean 'this dog growls and barks a lot, or smells very doggy, or something else'.